# Protocol-based or Browser-based load testing

Tags: performance-testing

Question: Hey guys, there is an e-commerce website which has lots of images & stuffs, it makes REST API & GraphQL calls to get the contents. The task is to determine performance of the website under some load, would protocol-based load tests be enough or do i need to go for browser-based load tests? And which tool would you guys suggest?

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

Well-behaved load test should mimic real users using real browsers so from the application under test point of view it should be no difference so consider simulating:

1. Handling [embedded resources](https://csswizardry.com/2018/06/image-inconsistencies-how-and-when-browsers-download-images/) (images, fonts, scripts, styles, etc) in the way browsers do
2. Don't forget about [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) because browsers fetch these resources only once (or according to [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers
3. Handling [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests in the way browsers do
4. Handling [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) in the way browsers do
5. You might still want to use 1 virtual user with 1 real browser driven i.e. via [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to check client-side performance, rendering speed, etc.

With regards to the tool you can consider using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) as its:

1. [Free and open source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter)
2. Capable of behaving like a [real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
3. Capable of simulating [AJAX](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md) requests
4. Can be integrated with [Selenium](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I've taken care of the first 3 points & it's working. Yet to explore the 4th one (integration of jmeter with selenium)